# Most efficient way to query one to many to many table relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have 3 MySQL tables that describe a game:

1. gamelist {gameId, ... with Primary(gameId) } = Stores information about each game session.
2. userlist {userId, ... with Primary(userId) } = Stores each user's information.
3. game2user {gameId, userId ... with Primary(gameId, userId) } = Stores which users are involved in each game session (one game session to two or more users).

Now, for a certain userId,  I need to retrieve a list of games that include the names of all the users involved in that game session.

The best I came out with so far is:

```
SELECT gl.gameid, gl.type, [...], ul.userid, ul.username
FROM userlist as ul, gamelist as gl, game2users as g2u
WHERE g2u.userid = a_certain_numeric_id AND
      ul.userid = g2u.userid AND
      gl.gameid = g2u.gameid`
```

This retrieves the unique rows from games list, but it only fetches the given user's username and not his co-players.

The question is how can I do this efficiently in terms of performance (time) and preferably without doing separate queries? Thanks.

Comment: You have the table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT gl.gameid, gl.type, ..., ul.userid, ul.username
FROM
    (
        SELECT gameid
        FROM game2users
        WHERE userid = a_certain_numeric_id
    ) AS ug
    INNER JOIN gamelist AS gl
        ON ug.gameid = gl.gameid
    INNER JOIN game2users AS g2u
        ON ug.gameid = g2u.gameid
    INNER JOIN userlist AS ul
        ON g2u.userid = ul.userid
```

Comment: This is the closest to what I want. I get rows for each game combination which is almost what I need. Is there a way to get a single row for each game session with all the users's names minus the current one's ?

Comment: The code that I've settled with is this: `SELECT
g.*, u.username
FROM
gamelist g
inner join game2users gu on gu.gameid = g.gameid
inner join game2users gu2 on 
gu2.gameid = gu.gameid
and gu2.userid = the_constant
inner join userlist u on u.userid = gu.userid
order by g.gameid, u.userid`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT gl.gameid, gl.type, [...], ul.userid, ul.username
FROM userlist as ul, gamelist as gl, game2users as g2u
WHERE ul.userid = g2u.userid AND
      g2u.gameid IN (SELECT gameid
                     FROM game2users
                     WHERE userid = a_certain_numeric_id);
```

This essentially looks for all games where the given user is involved (in the subquery) and then selects all users that are also involved in that games.

Answer (score -1):

The full schema for the tables and relationships would help us help you.

I'm not an expert on MySQL but it seems like you may be better off with a different implementation of the database (if you can change that). Right now you have redundant records in games2user table. I think the easiest thing would be to give the user table an attribute that contains the game they are involved in. Then when you do your query for this problem you can just query the gamesTable for the specific game that the user is involved in and retrieve all of the userIDs involved in that game.

Comment: The schema is correct and the standard way to handle many-to-many relationships in a relational DB. (i.e. a game can have many participants/users, and a user can be a participant in many games). By following your advice, you'd restrict the user to participate in at most one game at a time, which is not desired in this case. -1.